# DotLESS IIS7 is not working: LESS is not being rendered

Tags: iis, less, dotless

I've downloaded my dotless core dll from dotlesscss.org and completed all the steps required to properly use less in the project.

As they explain in the home webpage, i've included the reference to the .dll.

i added the httpHandler to the webconfig file just like they recommend

```
<add type="dotless.Core.LessCssHttpHandler,dotless.Core" validate="false" path="*.LESS" verb="*" />
```

**i've also created a configSection that a find out that if it's not the first child of configuration it will be returning 500 INTERNAL ERROR. (which is awesome)**

and added the  settings in as the child of  node, where it seems to be suppose to be.

None of the styles inside my less files which were included in the master page are being loaded. 
Any help?

Comment: mime types maybe?

look at http://tedgustaf.com/en/blog/2010/261/setup-dotless-in-aspnet-project/

and https://github.com/dotless/dotless/wiki/Using-.less

If you find a solution, feel free to add to the wiki.

Comment: actually setting up dotless in the correct way doesn't require you to setup mimetypes in your server. The settings required by dotless in the webconfig will tell the server how it should behavior when facing a .less file request (but the awnser is yes, i've tried it not only by changing the webconfig, but also by using the IIS7 gui and still doesn't work)
I've founded the solution using NuGet command line. It did all the job for me, handling all the depencies and placing those instructions lines required by the dotless in the web.config file.

Comment: @i forgot to say, there was small differences in the lines recommend at dotlesscss.org and the ones that the packmanager have installed in my web.config file. 
Tomorrow i'll leave the awnser to this post in the correct place. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: So hows that answer going, @Lothre1?

Comment: Yeah, how is answer going, @Lothre1?  :)

Comment: And how is answer going, @Lothre1 ?

Comment: Hey Lothre1, what's the answer?! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was having the same problem. What worked for me was putting the following web.config settings under system.webServer, instead of the suggested settings that the .less website shows under system.web:

```
<system.webServer>
  <handlers>
    <add name="dotless" path="*.LESS" verb="*" type="dotless.Core.LessCssHttpHandler,dotless.Core" resourceType="File" preCondition=""/>
  </handlers>
  <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
</system.webServer>
```

Source: http://cyrilgupta.com/?p=520

If you haven't already done so, you also need to add a MIME type for .less files in IIS, which I do not believe is listed in the instructions at dotlesscss.org.